# For Python programming and being Pythonic, why "never is often better than *right* now"?

Tags: python

In the Zen of Python, I can understand most parts of it, except:

```
Now is better than never.  
Although never is often better than *right* now
```

So I think doing it now or getting results now is better than never.  But why "never is often better than *right* now"? Or what does it mean?

To see the above 2 lines in context, this is the whole Zen of Python:

```
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
```

Comment: Cross-network dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20531943/3001761

Answer (score 13):

The first part, "now is better than never", is a mantra against procrastination. It expresses the idea that, if you don't get on with it, you'll never get around to it.

The second part, "never is often better than *right now*, is an expression of [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it) principle. The idea is that you should "Always implement things when you actually need them, never when you just foresee that you need them", because you often find that you don't need them after all, and then discover that you've just been wasting effort.

... well, that's my understanding. But you'd have to ask the author to be sure.

Comment: There is a quote from Chuck Moore that I feel expresses this sentiment nicely: “Do not put code in your program that might be used. Do not leave hooks on which you can hang extensions. The things you might want to do are infinite; that means that each has 0 probability of realization. If you need an extension later, you can code it later—and probably do a better job than if you did it now. And if someone else adds the extension, will he notice the hooks you left? Will you document this aspect of your program?”

Answer (score 2):

It could be about lazy evaluation.

Examples:

```
xrange(1000000)
```

vs

```
range(1000000)
```

Where the first doesn't do much until the values are needed but the latter allocates a big array.

Or logging

```
log("Stuff happened for %s ",  something)
```

vs

```
log("Stuff happened for %s " % something)
```

Where the first doesn't make the string unless logging is actually enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I think, these apply to the language design process itself, not only applications. "Now is better than never." and "Although never is often better than *right* now." is about finding right balance for time and quality of implementation. It is the same with the rest of the Zen. And, of course, Zen does not have a single meaning, by design.

Comment: yes, I saw it and found that it is like a Yin and Yang: Yin is better than Yang and Yang is better than Yin?  It might just be the right balance.

Answer (score 1):

> Now is better than never.
>   Although never is often better than *right* now

I think the first line refers to a mix of perfectionism and procrastination. It's better to provide something now that works, even if the functionality is basic or the code "not yet perfect", than to work on it forever until you run out of steam and the code just ends up dead.

As for the second line, I think it targets rushed implementations. Usually, the things you code have a very long lasting impact once released. Sometimes, one might be tempted to quickly ship something out, especially out of pressure, which will turn into a burden for the years after. It's called "technical debt":  poor design decisions, bad interfaces or just poor constructs lead to a lot of trouble down the road. Code is seldom alone, a lot of other code quickly builds upon it, and if you made a bad decisions, you're stuck with it. Therefore, don't rush releases, ensure it's fine stuff.